# Downloading files with loopback / express.js

Tags: node.js, download, loopbackjs

Here is the remote function:

```
  Document.download = async (id, res) => {
    try {
      const document = await Document.findById(id)
      res.set('Content-Type','application/octet-stream');
      res.set('Content-Type','application/download');
      res.set('Content-Transfer-Encoding','binary');

      const fileData = await readFile(document.path, { encoding: 'binary' })
      res.send(fileData);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
```

And the configuration of this remote method

```
  Document.remoteMethod(
    'download',
    {
      http: {path: '/:id/download', verb: 'get'},
      accepts: [
        { arg: 'id', type: 'string', required: true },
        { arg: 'res', type: 'object', 'http': { source: 'res' } }
      ],
      returns: [
          { arg: 'body', type: 'file', root: true }
      ]
    }
  )
```

If I try to download a txt file it works as expected. The downloaded file has the correct size. However if I try the same with a PDF, I am getting an empty file, with incorrect (bigger) size.

On the client side I have the following downloading code

```
        $.ajax(url, {cache: false}).success(function (data) {
          let blob = new Blob([data], {type: row.get('mimetype')});
          saveAs(blob, 'foo');
        });
```

Here is a screenshot of the response when I try to download a PDF. (Number of pages is correct, but they are blank)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is not on the server side, for example, this feature returns the wrong type: row.get ('mimetype').
There is a special component to work with files: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-storage

Comment: row.get ('mimetype') retruns **application/zip**, **application/pdf**, **text/plain** etc.  I think I already have an issue at server side, because the response's content size is bigger then the original file's size.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible to just send **res.download(path-to-file)**

Here is my sample code

```
app.get('/download/template-tenant', function(req, res) {
    const file = 'template/test.pdf';
    res.download(file);
});
```

Comment: thanks! could you please share your remote method definition? (how does your returns key look like?) How do you handle the download on client side? Do you provide a simple HTML a tag with the endpoint as href? or do you use some downloading library such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver?

Comment: Actually I load the function on startup by putting the function on server/boot folder, i edit the previous code